# Creating deployment from yaml file in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, minikube

I am trying to create a deployment using its deployment yaml file in minikube.
I have saved the deployment file locally.Please share the minikube kubectl command to create the deployment from the yaml file.

Answer (score 4):

Using native `kubectl` client you do this with the `kubectl apply` command and pass the `--filename` flag followed by the name of your yaml-file.

Example:

```
kubectl apply --filename my-deployment.yaml
```

When using [minikube kubectl](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/kubectl/) you prepend kubectl commands with `minikube`  and pass the command name after `--`, e.g.

```
minikube kubectl -- apply --filename my-deployment.yaml
```